# Geth; How to get balance of my address on main network

Tags: go-ethereum

I can't get my balance on main network.
How to get it by geth?

I created an account (0xaabbcc...) by MetaMask. And, I send some eth from my bitflyer account.

[image]

Then, I want to get the balance of my account. I have run geth by following command `geth --datadir="~/blockchain" --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr localhost --rpccorsdomain "*" --cache=1024 console 2>> geth.log`. And I executed `> eth.getBalance("0xaabbcc...")`, but that returned `0`.

Why can't I get my balance? Geth ver is `1.8.2-stable`.

my [geth.log](http://tttreal.com/tmp/geth.log)

Answer (score 1):

`getBalance()` can return 0 if the blockchain is not fully synchronized.

Check if `web3.eth.blockNumber` returns the latest block height.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I checked `web3.eth.blockNumber`, it returned 0 (´・ω・`)

Comment: That probably means your node is not syncing. Can you post the contents of `geth.log` ?

Comment: geth.log is so big...

Comment: Try `$ head -n 50 geth.log`

Comment: I posted the link of my geth.log.

Comment: And, I changed my database sometimes. Does `head 50` make any sense?

Comment: It seems to be syncing. Does `web3.eth.blockNumber` still return 0 ?

Comment: yes, return still 0.

Comment: ```eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 5492983,
  highestBlock: 5493048,
  knownStates: 65974394,
  pulledStates: 65966722,
  startingBlock: 5492717
}```

Comment: (My disk reach almost 100% )